# different color type and line type for multiple groups in survival curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a survival plot for three types of different cancers for two different populations. I want each cancer type to have one color and the difference between populations to be the line type (dashed vs solid). So cancer A would be red, with PopA having dashed line and PopB having solid line, an so on.

I cannot seem to get the one color for each Cancer group and then alter linetype between populations.

I cannot post all the data here since it is protected, but here is the df, the surv function and the ggsurvplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(KMsurv)
library(ggfortify)
library(ggthemes)

> srv_time_mon <- sample(0:100,200, replace = TRUE)
> cancer <- sample(1:3,200, replace = TRUE)
> alive <- sample(0:1,200, replace = TRUE)
> pop <- sample(1:2,200, replace = TRUE)
> dead <- sample(0:1,200, replace = TRUE)
> df <- data.frame(srv_time_mon,cancer, alive, pop, dead)

> head(df)
  srv_time_mon cancer alive pop dead
1           84      1     0   1    1
2           91      2     0   2    0
3           44      1     0   2    1
4           57      2     1   1    0
5           54      1     1   2    0
6           31      3     0   2    1

test <- survfit(Surv(srv_time_mon, dead)~pop+cancer, data=df)

 ggsurvplot(test, data=df, conf.int = FALSE, 
       pval = "Log-Rank p <0.001", title="Kaplan-Meier Curves", break.time.by=12,
       risk.table = TRUE, 
       pval.coord=c(156,0.60), surv.median.line = "v", 
       legend.labs=c("Pop A Cancer 1", "Pop A Cancer 2", "Pop A Cancer 3", "Pop B Cancer 1",
       "Pop B Cancer 2", "Pop B Cancer 3"), 
       legend.title="", legend = c(0.8,0.83), linetype = c("pop"), palette = "jco")+ 
       scale_linetype_discrete( name="Pop Data", labels=c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the `class` of the object that `ggsurvplot()` returns, let's call it `p`, you'll notice it's not a `ggplot` object

```
class(p)
#[1] "ggsurvplot" "ggsurv"     "list"
```

You'll find the `ggplot` object here

```
class(p$plot)
#[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

If you now run

```
p$plot + scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Pop Data", labels = c("A", "B"))
```

you'll see this plot:

[image]

Now if you want one legend, change the `linetype` argument in the `ggsurvplot()` call to `"strata"` such that the two legends are combined because now the same variable is mapped to different aesthetics.

Finally add `scale_linetype_manual()` and `scale_colour_manual()` to `p$plot`.

See full code below.

[image]

```
p <- ggsurvplot(
  test,
  data = df,
  conf.int = FALSE,
  pval = "Log-Rank p <0.001",
  title = "Kaplan-Meier Curves",
  break.time.by = 12,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  pval.coord = c(156, 0.60),
  surv.median.line = "v",
  legend.labs = c(
    "Pop A Cancer 1",
    "Pop A Cancer 2",
    "Pop A Cancer 3",
    "Pop B Cancer 1",
    "Pop B Cancer 2",
    "Pop B Cancer 3"
  ),
  legend.title = "",
  # legend = c(0.8, 0.83), # took this out for cleaner appearance of the legend (optional)
  linetype = c("strata"), # changed from "pop" to "strata"
  palette = "jco"
)
```

I assume you want the colours for cancer types 2 and 3 to be black. Change code below if you want different colours.

```
cols <-  rep(c("red", "black"), c(2, 4))
#cols <-  rep(c("red", "forestgreen", "lightblue"), 2) # example
names(cols) <- paste("Pop", rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3), "Cancer", 1:3)

lines <-  rep(c("dashed", "solid"), each = 3)
names(lines) <- paste("Pop", rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3), "Cancer", 1:3)

p$plot <- p$plot + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lines) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

---

Add the risk table (another `ggplot` object) beneath the plot using the [`patchwork` package](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork).

```
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
p$plot / p$table + plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(3, 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = rev(cols)))
```

[image]

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  srv_time_mon = sample(0:100, 200, replace = TRUE),
  cancer = sample(1:3, 200, replace = TRUE),
  alive = sample(0:1, 200, replace = TRUE),
  pop = sample(1:2, 200, replace = TRUE),
  dead = sample(0:1, 200, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this figure. At the step where you add `scale_linetype_manual` and `scale_colour_manual`, the resulting `print(p)` throws an error: "Error in names(cols) <- legend.labs : 'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [2]".`